# Saber linha e arquivo que está executando um método

Tags: php

Quero saber se é possível saber a linha e arquivo que está sendo executado um método. Por exemplo, tenho uma class `Log`, com ela faço registros de logs dos usuários.

## Log.php

```
<?php
/**
* Classe de Logs
*/
class Log
{
   var $con;

   private $error, $orig;

   function __construct($userid = NULL) {
      global $con;
      $this->con = $con;
      $this->obs = '';
   }

   function SetError($error, $type = 1, $concat = FALSE, $register = TRUE){
      $this->error = ($concat ? $this->error."\n ".$error : $error);
      $this->orig = 'Arquivo: '.__FILE__."\n Linha: ".__LINE__;
      if($register) $this->RegisterLog($error);
      return FALSE;
   }
```

## Arte.php <sup>(linha 85)</sup>

```
  } else return $this->SetError('Não foi possível carregar os produtos.');
```

<sub>**NOTA:** A CLASSE `ARTE` ESTENDE A CLASSE `LOG`</sub>

Quando entrasse nessa linha, gostaria que a variável `$this->orig` tivesse o seguinte valor:

> Arquivo: C:\xampp\htdocs\projeto\app\class\Arte.php Linha: 85

Mas vem o valor:

> Arquivo: C:\xampp\htdocs\projeto\app\class\Log.php Linha: 19

É possível fazer isso? Tem alguma outra alternativa que posso fazer?

**PS.:** Se possível gostaria de não passar essas informações por parâmetros, pois teria que mexer em muita coisa.

Comment: Se disparar uma exception não resolve o problema?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode fazer usando a função **debug_backtrace()** :

```
class Caller extends Log {

    function test() {
        // Chama a função na classe log
        parent::setLog();
    }

}

class Log {
    // Metodo de log
    public function setLog() {
        var_dump(debug_backtrace());
    }

}

$caller = new Caller();
$caller->test();
```

**Saída:**

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=7)
      'file' => string '/home/edi/NetBeansProjects/zion/testes/test.php' (length=47)
      'line' => int 7
      'function' => string 'setLog' (length=6)
      'class' => string 'Log' (length=3)
      'object' => 
        object(Caller)[1]
      'type' => string '->' (length=2)
      'args' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
  1 => 
    array (size=7)
      'file' => string '/home/edi/NetBeansProjects/zion/testes/test.php' (length=47)
      'line' => int 24
      'function' => string 'test' (length=4)
      'class' => string 'Caller' (length=6)
      'object' => 
        object(Caller)[1]
      'type' => string '->' (length=2)
      'args' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Comment: Parece que satisfaz o meu problema, essa função é nativa, certo? Vou testar mais tarde e dou um retorno.

Comment: Só um detalhe: não é necessário o Xdebug para usar essa função.

Comment: Bem observado, corrigi a resposta.

Comment: Muito bom era exatamente isso que eu queria, e ainda melhor. :D Ainda consegui mais detalhes, como classe, método e etc. Valeu!